# How to fix wrong style of Angular Material Radio Button on Edge and Mac's Chrome?

Tags: angular-material

I got the issue with the Angular material radio button on Edge and Mac'chrome.
The position of solid circle inside selected button is not at the center as picture below. 
[image]

Thanks for the fixing in advance.

Comment: Can you post your markup and CSS? Also, inspect the style of the button in the console and see if anything is affecting it.

Comment: Hi @camden_kid , There is no customized css. It happens in current release version of Angular Material. You can see the issue at [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBpgOd)

Comment: It looks okay on Chrome on a Mac. The solid circle is centred.

Comment: @camden_kid It works correctly on Mac's chrome. Thanks for your check.